# Why run-time populated array does not work on NgModule declarations?

Tags: angular

[image]

While fixed array works?

[image]

I would like to use this extractor of components from routes:

```js
function* getRoutesComponents(routes: Routes) {
    for (const route of routes) {
        if (route.component) {
            yield route.component;

            if (route.children) {
                yield* getRoutesComponents(route.children);
            }
        }
    }
}



@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)],
    declarations: getRoutesComponents(ROUTES)
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

So I can avoid missing a component declaration in declarations property. Missing a component in declarations would result to error: [NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://www.anicehumble.com/2020/03/ng8002-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-known-property-of-input.html)

Comment: I have tried to replicate your scenario in a sample app here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-ngjjen?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts and it is working fine only.. ```childcomponent``` and ```appcomponent``` are pushed into ```a``` and it is loaded..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan interesting your example works. I'm using this example: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing. Perhaps there's some  angular or typescript settings on that project that makes the angular or typescript reads the NgModule statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable [runtime population of components](https://www.anicehumble.com/2020/03/extracting-components-from-angular-routes.html) for declarations, we need to disable Angular's AOT. This can be done by setting the `ng serve` or `ng build`'s `--aot` to false.

[image]

However, disabling AOT would cause two major inconveniences. First, we cannot use constants as keys on objects anymore. Second, when AOT is disabled, despite `fullTemplateTypeCheck` is set to true, Angular will still build the project even if the names binded to ngModel have typo or spelling mistakes.